# How to convert RestSharp AddFile to work on Binary Data?

Tags: c#, asp.net, restsharp

My code includes this line which works very well:

`request.AddFile("file", "C:\\Users\\data\\Downloads\\data.docx");`

Now, I need to replace the file content with bytes[] array accepted as a variable (data_for_reqeust):

```
public void MssUploadSignFile(byte[] data_for_request)
{
request.AddHeader(....)
request.AddFile("file", data_for_request);
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
}
```

This obviously doesn't work, so how could I keep the same functionality of AddFile but with bytes[] data?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of addFile can you try:

request.AddParameter("application/octet-stream", data_for_request, ParameterType.RequestBody);

Comment: I tried to replace with your suggestion:
request.AddParameter("application/octet-stream", data_for_request ,ParameterType.RequestBody); 
But I encounter a BadRequest error message